# Programs autostarting, but not in list?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, autostart

Background: Whenever I log into my account, gmusicbrowser and two chromium windows open. I checked my list of autostarting programs in the settings manager, and they aren't in it: [image]

Question: Why are these opening? What can I do to stop them from opening?

Comment: What 'list' is this?

Comment: The list of programs that autostart in `Settings Manager -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart` - changed in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, silly me - the answer was a pretty dumb mistake.

I had unknowingly had "Save session for future logins" checked, which when I logged out saved having chrome and gmusicbrowser open, thus causing every login afterwards to automatically open these programs.

Solved this by closing everything, checking "Save session for future logins", and logging out. Logged back in, and nothing opened!