# How find out what is autostarting my terminal?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, autostart, terminator

I have Xubuntu 16.04 with XFCE window manager.

Every time when I start my computer, the terminal of [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) is also autostarting.

When I look into "Session and Startup", , I found nothing which relates to Terminator. And "Automatically save session on logout" is also unchecked.

In the Terminator settings, there is no autostart option available.

In the following folders:

```
~/.config/autostart
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

There are no contents related to Terminator, so it's scratching my mind where Terminator autostartup come from.

When I change the name Terminator as following

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/terminator.backup(
```

and rebooting, Terminator is indeed not starting. Looking into my logs on `/var/log`, grepping for anything that would relate to Terminator, I found nothing.

Any suggestion to find out which process is responsible for the autostarting Terminator?

Comment: Check your .bashrc file.

Comment: I use Fish and Bash, but in both files there is no command that calls terminator. To be sure, I removed my `.bashrc ` and fish configuration file, and rebooted. But Terminator is still popping up...

Comment: Does it help if you clear the session cache? To do that choose the `Session`-tab in the `Session and Startup`-window and click the `Clear saved sessions`-button.

Comment: What does `pstree -psa <pid-of-terminator>` report? There's also `~/.config/upstart`, `~/.config/systemd` for init-system based user-session autostart.

Comment: could be a duplicate see https://askubuntu.com/questions/228762/programs-autostarting-but-not-in-list?rq=1

Comment: @ReneFroger - is there somewhere like this: desktop settings ? (similiar to gnome-tweak-tools in gnome) - then there would be pre-defined which programs start at login like for welcoming you.

Answer (score 1):

`pstree` is the best way I can think of.

First you need to find the PID of your `terminator` session you want to trace. I use `gnome-terminal` so I would use:

```
$ ps aux | grep gnome-terminal
rick     10321  0.0  0.0  14524  1088 pts/18   S+   20:49   0:00 grep --color=auto gnome-terminal
rick     12871  0.0  0.4 538372 37968 ?        Sl   Jun10   0:31 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

The first PID is the `ps aux` command itself so ignore that. You will have two other PIDs, one for the ghost and one for the ghost-hunter session. Use this to display the `pstree` for both PIDs:

```
$ pstree -sapl 12871
systemd,1 splash fastboot kaslr
  └─lightdm,1050
      └─lightdm,1597 --session-child 12 19
          └─upstart,1891 --user
              └─gnome-terminal-,12871
                  ├─bash,12879
                  ├─bash,15278
                  │   └─pstree,21311 -sapl 12871
                  ├─{dconf worker},12873
                  ├─{gdbus},12875
                  └─{gmain},12874
```

The `pstree` will trace back all parent processes to your `terminator` sessions based on PID (Process Identification).